# Conditional Variables in Azure Classic Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a variable in the Azure Build Pipelines Classic Editor to use conditional functions to determine its value.  YAML is not an option (unless there's some way to inject YAML as part of a Classic build...?).

In my current scenario, the idea is that the variable would return one of a few possible string values (or empty string) depending on the branch that triggered the build.

I want something along the lines of this:

[image]

I fear this may be a YAML-only thing, but hopefully someone can tell me I'm wrong about that.

Comment: I don't think that is a thing.  I have had some difficulty just getting it to replace a simple variable substitution.  I'd probably recommend if you want something complex to put it in an inline powershell that using the ##[vso] commands to set the variable how you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Matt mentioned in the comment, the best approach for this would be to use a script (powershell or bash) that will have the logic to set the variable.

For more details about how to set a variable, have a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

Comment: Thanks for this.  For my particular situation, I found a workaround which involved using the conditions I wanted to check for as a way to decide between three different tasks, each with their own variable.  Depending on the value of the condition (the source branch in my example), only one of the three tasks would run, and they would use the correct version of the variable.  It was a little redundant, but got the job done.  In a scenario where that wouldn't work, I will most likely use this PowerShell approach). I think it's safe to say that ADO doesn't support what I was trying to do.